# IIR design: SciPy CMSIS-DSP coefficient format

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, scipy, embedded-systems

How do you reconcile Scipy.signal's IIR design with CMSIS-DISP's API? Scipy.signal outputs in one of 3 forms:

- Numerator/denominator
- Pole Zero
- Second-Order-Sections.

CMSIS requires an array of length a multiple of five. Each 5 values are coefficients b0, b1, b2, a1, and a2 for a filter state: "*Coefficients b0, b1 and b2 multiply the input signal x[n] and are referred to as the feedforward coefficients. Coefficients a1 and a2 multiply the output signal y[n] and are referred to as the feedback coefficients. Pay careful attention to the sign of the feedback coefficients. Some design tools use the difference equation*"

Scipy's formats seem incompatible: Numerator/Denominator uses "b" and "a" terminology, but returns 2 arrays: A numerator array of lengh 6, and denominator array of len 6.
SOS format also returns arrays of length 6.

This is in contrast to FIR, where there's a 1-to-1 mapping. Ie both use an array of coefficients corresponding to a convolution kernel. IIR seems more diverse by comparison.

[scipy.signal.iirdesign](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirdesign.html)

[CMSIS-DSP Biquad Cascade](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html)

Comment: CMIS uses a standard normalized second order sections. They just assume that $a_0=1$ and you don't specifically pass it into the function, so you pass in 5 coefficients instead of 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scipy.signal` returns a sos matrix when you set `output='sos'`, which is cascaded second-order sections and has a shape of `(n_sections, 6)`.

Each row corresponds to a second-order section, and you have `[b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2]` in order. Normalize these coefficients to make sure that `a0=1`, and then remove `a0` from the array -- CMSIS assumes that `a=1` so you only need 5 coefficients.

One thing to mention is that the sign of the denominators are different in scipy and CMSIS. The difference equation defined in CMSIS is given by

$$
y[n] = b_0  x[n] + b_1  x[n-1] + b_2  x[n-2] - a_1  y[n-1] - a_2  y[n-2]
$$

However it is defined in scipy/MATLAB by
$$
y[n] = b_0  x[n] + b_1  x[n-1] + b_2  x[n-2] + a_1  y[n-1] + a_2  y[n-2]
$$

So you have to change the signs of all the denominators. And finally, cascade coefficients of all sections and you get array of length `n_sections * 5`:

$$
[b_0^1, b_1^1, b_2^1, -a_1^1, -a_2^1, b_0^2, b_1^2, b_2^2, -a_1^2, -a_2^2,\ldots, b_0^N, b_1^N, b_2^N, -a_1^N, -a_2^N]
$$
where $N$ is the number of biquad sections, which is defined as `numStages` in CMSIS.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for (how to run a scipy-generated filter in CMSIS), thanks! Stuff like this should be in the CMSIS documentation

Comment: However, something might have changed, because the difference equation specified in CMSIS now is y[n] = b0 * x[n] + b1 * x[n-1] + b2 * x[n-2] + a1 * y[n-1] + a2 * y[n-2] (with positive a1 and a2), see https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html

Comment: I think the scipy convention is -a1, -a2, so the end result is correct that you need to negate them, but for the opposite reasons as in the answer :)